# Which DB? Linq to SQL classes

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sqlite, database

I want to develop a multiuser supporting accounting management application in C#.

I want to use Linq To SQL classes. LINQ to SQL only supports SQL Server/Compact. However is it possible the SQLite people have written their own LINQ provider given the name of the assembly.

I have to use DBMS that is FREE. Which DBMS do you suggest to me?

Answer (score 3):

LIN2SQL = SQL Server. Second class badly written O/R mapper compared to the real contendors (like NHibernate).

LINQ2SQL != LINQ. LINQ is the query integration into the langauge, and supported by pretty much a lot of O/R mappers out there, and some databases.

> I have to use Db that is FREE.

Free like for free? What is against sql server? Express edition - 0 USD. And the 4gb "database size limit" does not stop you from writing accounting systems. THat is a LOT of space for accounting data. For many years of accounting data.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Linq-to-SQL (which I think is an excellent choice) you have to use some variant of MSSQL. Both Sql Server Compact and Sql Server Express are free to use. If you have a multiuser scenario you will have to go for Sql Server Express as Sql Server Compact doesn't allow multiple simultaneous access.

Comment: Agreed, SQL Server Express is FREE and would fit well within your requirements. If you don't want to use SQL Server, LINQ to SQL is not what you should be using.

Answer (score 0):

There are various experimental linq to sql and linq to entity framework providers for other databases(like mysql and postgres) - in my experience they are so immature it is not worth using for anything serious.

For now, I'd suggest you'd look for something else if you cannot use SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following link:

http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/

Note that Linq2SQL is not compatible with SQLite, however the link points to an Entity Framework provider for SQLite.  EF is kind of like Linq2SQL on steroids.  SQLite is very lightweight, so the EF implementation above should work nicely for your needs.